# Retrieving original body from an http error in Guzzle

Tags: php, guzzle

I'm making a [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) request to an api, and

```
$request = $this->client->request('GET', 'https://etc', ['http_errors' => false]);
```

I've had to turn http_errors off as if the API wants to tell me something it does it as a JSON response but it also has a header code of 402.

I can get the response headers back from Guzzle, but I'm unable to get the actual body `$request->getBody()` as this is just an empty stream on the response object.

Does anyone know how I retrieve the original page despite it providing a 402 http error.

NB: If I don't turn off `http_errors`, it will throw an exception but the message is wrapped (and truncated).

Any suggestions would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled across the answer I was looking for.

If I don't turn off http_errors and catch the exception I can run

`$e->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents();`

to retrieve the contents of the request.